# What's the best place for questions about a specific product for light control

Tags: discussion

I've been looking around StackExchange for the best place to ask/answer questions about products for light control (DMX and RDM). For example questions on how to configure software XYZ to work with hardware ABC. These are products for professionals (light designers, theater lighting, DJs, etc) so not home-use, but I wasn't sure if this community was the best place, and if not where do you recommend these are discussed?
I've also checked some other communities like Super User, but they seem to be more geared towards home users and more general computer questions. The light control questions are not necessary computer-related (but most are).

Obviously a wiki/forums by the manufacturers may be the best spot, but I was hoping StackExchange would be a more open place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal feelings are that it is on topic.  It became less clear after Audio split off to Sound Design.  But such things were certainly on topic for AVP and I would personally still like to see them handled here and I think there is enough of an arguable touch point on video production specifically.

Ultimately, there is a decent chance of the community deciding they don't want that kind of question here, but thus far it looks like the only responses have been in favor.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds on-topic to me, but you may have better luck at Creative Cow's [Lighting Design Pros](https://forums.creativecow.net/lightingdesignpros) forum.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I think the article style at StackExchange is better suited, especially when there's more a Q and A and less discussion among users.

Comment: The format may be more to your liking, but the audience at that link seems narrower and more suited to the topic at hand. Frankly, this SE is low on regular users and breadth of experts who hang around.

Comment: I'm actually looking more for a place where I can post my answers as well as questions and then it'll be like a knowledge base that span multiple (related) products and help regular users, or I can direct users here who ask me about these questions. I did a post as a test here: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/17288/configure-freestyler-to-work-with-dmxking-ultradmx-rdm-pro-micro